# 'tab' is not a known element errors when adding ng2-bootstrap to angular2-seed

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

I am trying to add **ng2-bootstrap** into a *fresh clone* of the **angular2-seed** project, but I keep getting the following error (or similar):

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: 'tab' is not a known element
```

I have followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed/wiki/Add-external-dependency) and tried several variations, but it just doesn't want to work. I have it working in other projects that use different versions of angular2-seed, so perhaps something has changed that isn't documented in their wiki yet.

I have created a repo demonstrating my problem: https://github.com/danielcrisp/angular2-seed

As I said it is a fresh clone of angular2-seed, with the following changes:

`$ npm install ng2-bootstrap --save`

Then update the config:

```
this.SYSTEM_CONFIG_DEV.paths['ng2-bootstrap'] =
  `${this.APP_BASE}node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap.js`;

this.SYSTEM_BUILDER_CONFIG.packages['ng2-bootstrap'] = {
    main: 'ng2-bootstrap.js',
    defaultExtension : 'js'
};
```

Import `Ng2BootstrapModule` into the `NgModule`.

And then I added some tabs to test.

```
<tabset>
  <tab>1</tab>
  <tab>2</tab>
</tabset>
```

If I remove the tabs from the HTML I get no errors. I also get errors if I try other ng2-bootstrap components, e.g.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" [(ngModel)]="singleModel" btnCheckbox btnCheckboxTrue="1" btnCheckboxFalse="0">`
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It turns out that I needed to include `Ng2BootstrapModule` into every sub-`NgModule` that uses it, rather than just the main root `NgModule`.

Importing `Ng2BootstrapModule` into the `home.module.ts` did the trick.

Thanks to @mgechev for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Problem Solved for 'tabset' is not a known element:

1. If 'tabset' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

In App.module.ts

```js
Add import { TabsModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/tabs';

Import:[TabsModule.forRoot()]
```

Answer (score -1):

Even with ng2-bootstrap added to your project you still need to include the style sheets from the cdn and module in your index.html. Give the [quick start](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap#quick-start) a look over and make sure you didn't miss anything.

Comment: I know the CSS is missing, but that's not a problem - it won't cause this error. I don't need to include the module in the HTML when using Angular2-seed.